# AWT and text fields

Tags: java, awt, textfield

I'm newby in AWT and I've got some questions.
How move text fields to the left?
How to move second text field to next line?
This is my init():

```
public void init() {
        setSize(500, 200);
        encode = new Button("Encode");
        Label valueL = new Label("Text:");
        Label codeLabel = new Label("Crypt:");
        text = new TextField(12);
        codeField = new TextField(12);
        add(valueL);
        add(text);
        add(encode);
        add(codeLabel);
        add(codeField);
        text.addActionListener(this);
        encode.addActionListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the newer Swing?

Comment: I use AWT for academic purposes.

Comment: You must use layout managers: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Other link: http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/ui/layout/index.html

Comment: Does 'academic purposes' mean the prof. specified AWT components?  I ask because for *learning purposes*, it would be far more optimal to teach Swing components.  Many of the people who ever used AWT components have not used them for so long that they forget the details. As a result, most current info. on AWT is flawed, and the old information is obsolescent (e.g. using deprecated methods).

Answer (score 1):

You must use layout managers. Some usefull links:

[docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

[journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/ui/layout/index.html](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/ui/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));` to create a new JPanel.

Add you elements to the new `JPanel` like so.

`panel.add(text);`
`panel.add(codeField);`

also see:

[How can I align all elements to the left in JPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714663/how-can-i-align-all-elements-to-the-left-in-jpanel)